# Change the "temp" folder used when zipping/archiving files?

Tags: windows, zip

I'm trying to zip up a huge file, but it fails since my C:\ drive doesn't have enough space. How do change it to use another drive?

Comment: Set the `%Temp%` variable to whatever path you would like to use, e.g. `F:/Temp/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Hesse said, change the Environment Path `%Temp%` to an alternate location. You can do this by **Right-Clicking** on **My Computer** then selecting **Properties**. If you are using Windows 7 you will have to click on the link **"Advanced System Settings"** in the pane on the left. Select the **Advanced** tab. Click on the button named "**Environment Variables**".

Select `%Temp%` from the list and **edit** it with the new location.

All programs that use the Temp directory will now use the new path specified.

Comment: @john2x Prefer to not put it on a disk that would be removed. Before you think about changing disk/partiton letters, rearranging disks, or having disk problems, **rememeber** that you change it.  the system itself can often cope without it being right, but some programs using it wont.

Comment: Thanks. Does this require a reboot?

Comment: This worked great, thanks. One extra step I had to do was to log out then log back in for this to work.

Comment: My %TEMP% and %TMP% variables are pointed on a non-boot drive as to take a load off the boot drive. So is my paging file.